# Ajax onComplete and onSuccess functions in Prototype JS

Tags: ajax, prototypejs

What comes first when using Ajax in Prototype Js - call of onComplete or onSuccess function? I thought onSuccess should be first, but when my code is executed, onComplete is always first... You know why?

The code is:

```
request =   new Ajax.Request(
            this.saveUrl,
            {
                method:     'post',
                onComplete: this.shippingSave(wait),
                onSuccess:  this.onSave, 
...
```

Comment: Actually the documentation lists them in the order onSuccess -> onComplete, and looking at the code they are fired in that order. Which browser is this in and can you put a `console.log` as the first call in the callback functions to check which is getting called first? There is a possibility your onComplete function returns or invokes an async method that allows onSuccess to fire and onSuccess is a shorter function.

Comment: I found out that what matters is sort order of onComplete and onSuccess... Odd :( But now I changed sort order and onSuccess is called first and onComplete second if I use console.log. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: There is another problem - onSuccess function just doesn't wait to finish - it goes immediately to onComplete. Do you know why?